# Automapper not setting navigation property values from stored procedure

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, automapper

My `Customer.Model` has a navigation property:

```
public Address Address { get; set; }
```

I have a stored procedure that has a select that looks like the following:

```
 SELECT 
     c.*, 
     a.City AS AddressCity, 
     a.State AS AddressState
```

These values end up in a complex object that EF6 auto generates:

```
Customer_GetCustomers_Result
```

In my AutoMapper config I have:

```
CreateMap<Customer_GetCustomers_Result, Model.Customer>();
```

In my Repository I have:

```
public IEnumerable<Model.Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    var cList = context.Customer_GetCustomers();
    return Mapper.Map<List<Model.Customer>>(cList);
}
```

`cList` ends up being of type `Customer_GetCustomers_Result` so AutoMapper converts it to `Model.Customer` and returns so my app can use it.

I was told AutoMapper will automatically set `Customer.Address.City` and `Customer.Address.State` if I followed that naming convention. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your referring to what's called [*flattening*](https://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Flattening). But it's the other way around. AutoMapper can map `Customer.Address.City` to a property `Target.AddressCity`, but not the reverse. It would have to create an `Address` object and only set its `City` property, and then keep in mind that for the second mapping the same `Address` should be used.

Just too many intricacies and edge cases to get involved in for a tool that's supposed to do a straightforward job.

Comment: So working with Entity Framework 6 and stored procs isn't going to work out for me then because in the end I expect my model to have that property. If it isn't my model it would be my view model. Any other suggestions just to get all the way from my Data Layer (auto generated ef6 dbfirst layer) to my Model Layer (poco layer) to my Web Layer with proc results to models?